# Is installing Visual studio 2015 enterprise edition sufficient to work with C++11/C++14?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I want to work with C++ 11 (if not C++ 14). I am installing visual studio 2015 enterprise edition. Is this sufficient?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx.

Comment: Enterprise costs several thousand dollars per year. If you need to ask strangers about this and not your manager, it's not for you. Consider the Community edition.

Comment: You could also use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). Both are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) compilers that you would use on the command line (or with some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool). You might even install and use some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution), which is developer friendly. Your tool recommendation question is **off-topic** on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes. Most of C++11 has been implemented in VS2015. Most of C++14 has been implemented in VS2017.

Completely? No.

There are still various missing features (expression SFINAE) and bugs in the Microsoft compiler implementations of C++. If and when you run into these limitations depends on the style of code you write.

Comment: While this does seem to answer the question as asked, the specifics are too vague to be useful for future visitors. Can you point to your source?

Comment: My source is trying to compile code using expression SFINAE (just try to use the "detection idiom"; you'll not be able to). There are various omissions in the documentation so that there is no MSDN link I can give you to show what exactly is missing. Heck, they still don't properly implement C++98 last I checked. There are also bugs related to not properly choosing the auto-generated move constructor for classes containing vectors of e.g. unique_ptr's. Again, anecdotal real life issues I've come across on a day-to-day basis. I don't keep track, I just curse hard, work around the issue, and mov

Comment: The latest official report is here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/19/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/ where expression SFINAE is listed as "partial", as are some other things.

Comment: For one thing, std::align is not in that list, and is unimplemented in VS2015. That list is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) or [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

A screenshot from MSDN：

[image]